# UIButton: Setting background image to the disabled state changes display of the default state

Tags: ios, uibutton

In Storyboard I defined a `UIButton` that has to be enabled/disabled by program. Its default state has no background image, and the title "Default". If its disabled state has neither a background image, and just a different title "Disabled", and I switch between both states by program, the `UIButton` is displayed in both states in the simulator and a device as expected:[image]
However, if I assign only to the disabled state a background image, the `UIButton` is displayed in the disabled state as expected, but the default state has now a transparent image and background image, i.e., only the title is displayed:
[image]
I expected that assigning a background image to the disabled state does not change the assignment to the default state. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Set the backgroundImage to nil when re-enabling:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

This makes my button appear normal again.

Additional Reading: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIButtonType

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. However, the only thing I do -after assigning the background image - is to set the enable property to YES or NO.

Comment: There is nearly no code to show except the assignment to the property, e.g. self.deleteCoordinatesButton.enabled = NO; Everything else is set up in the storyboard.

Comment: Oddly enough, setting the background image for state normal did not work for me. I had to set the background image for state disabled to nil in order to get the right image. Anyway, +1 for your efforts, thanks!

Comment: Woops, my mistake on the forState:UIControlStateNormal.  I've updated my post to reflect the correct answer.  Glad it worked for you!