# Setting a background image for highlighted state removes automatic highlight

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm implementing a checkbox subclass of a UIButton. There are 2 background images (on/off) and 4 conceptual states:

- `on` - on image / not highlighted
- `off` - off image / not highlighted
- `on & pressed` - on image / highlighted
- `off & pressed` - off image / highlighted

If I set background images for only on and off (`UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateSelected`), the button gets highlighted when held.

However, when `on & pressed`, it uses the off image (as expected, because the state is `UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted`, so it uses the normal state image)

So I set the background image for `UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted` to be the on image, but now the programmatic highlight is disabled - I assume because if you set a specific background image for that state the logic is you probably want to override the highlight.

I don't want to use a third image, is it possible to set a background image for `UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted` and still have the programmatic highlight get applied?

I'm already calling `[self setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];` after setting the background image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a `UIButton` whose type is not "custom" but e.g. "Rounded Rect". In this case setting a background image can have unexpected side effects, see my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481204/uibutton-setting-background-image-to-the-disabled-state-changes-display-of-the).
I suggest to change the button type to "custom". Then of course you have to define all attributes by your own.

Comment: I'm not sure if/how I can set the button type in the class itself, but the way I use it is in IB I add a UIButton, set it's type to `Custom`, and set it's class to be `MyCheckBoxClass`. The class is derived directly from UIButton. Update: in the class's initWithCoder (where I set the images), the type is `UIButtonTypeCustom`